# Got an error with running "pip install -e . " command after I installed Jaclang, using "pip install jaclang"

Tags: pip

I have run "pip install -e . " command and got an error like this..

```
PS C:\Users\ShanDilranga> pip install -e.
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/ShanDilranga
ERROR: file:///C:/Users/ShanDilranga does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

after that I navigated to the place where pyproject.toml located, and ran again "pip install -e ."
then got an error like this,

```
PS C:\Users\ShanDilranga\AppData\Local\Programs\Jetbrains\plugins\python-ce\helpers\typeshed> pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/ShanDilranga/AppData/Local/Programs/Jetbrains/plugins/python-ce/helpers/typeshed
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['stubs', 'stdlib', 'test_cases'].

      To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
      setuptools will not proceed with this build.

      If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
      on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
      Instead, consider the following options:

      1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
      2. use a `src-layout`
      3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names

      To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I couldn't find a way to solve this.

I have tried with windows powershell and tried under the linux environment using WSL as well.  got the same error

Comment: Well it clearly explains what the problem is / what it thinks it is, and offers you options. You should really explain in your question if you've done any of those, or if that reason is accurate etc.